# Some commands are no longer responding?

Tags: shell, kali-linux, gcc, man

I have a `Debian` based distribution & lately a problem has been encountered when trying to execute the `gcc` or `man` command's (And probably other commands I haven't found yet).

When I type them in the shell nothing happens, as though I hit enter for a new line. I have tried to use an absolute path, but the same thing occurs.

- I  have also checked the executable & installation files and everything looks OK.
- I have restored the `$PATH` variable, I made and update && upgrade & a build-essential.
- I also deleted GCC package & reinstalled

But nothing has made a difference. Please can you tell me what's the problem ?

Example:

```
root@afr0ck:~# man ls 
root@afr0ck:~#

root@afr0ck:~# gcc 
root@afr0ck:~#
```

(I have even tried from another terminal & with a different user).

Comment: Have you tried `/usr/bin/man ls`?  Do you have a `ls` alias or shell function in your environment that is somehow broken?

Comment: what is the exit code from your failed commands ? like `man ls;echo $?`... what does it return ? a zero or non-zero ?

Comment: Related to @DopeGhoti's suggestion, can you do a `type gcc` and `type man` and let us know what it says?

Comment: `type man` returns this: root@afr0ck:~# type man man is hashed (/usr/bin/man) and `man ls;echo $?` returns 0 : root@afr0ck:~# man ls;echo $? 0

Comment: Install `strace` if necessary, and run `strace -o man.strace -s9999 -f man ls` and post the whole content of `man.strace`.

Comment: Sorry for being too late,i had to solve some technical issues before i could post comments.Well,the problem is still up,i noticed that all binary files of broken commands are 0kb in size (like man,locate,awk,nano...).What could be the problem after that ? (i didn't mention that im running Kali Linux which is a debian based dist).
@DopeGhoti

Comment: @AndyDalton i have already answred you in previous comment but forgot to tag,you can read the comment before that one for additional info.

Comment: If the executables are zero-byte files, that's likely the problem.  Reinstalling the packages should fix this for think like `gcc`, but I'm hard-pressed to come up with a nonmalicious reason for `ls` to be similarly zeroed out.

Comment: I agree with @DopeGhoti -- the zero-byte executables are the problem.  Running a zero-byte program will result in a successful exit status.  Have you had filesystem problems?